# How to remove a value from a postgres text column json string array?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a postgresql table with a column that is a text datatype. This column value is a JSON string array. These values could be in any order such as

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

or

```
["c", "a", "b", "d"]
```

or

```
["a"]
```

Now one of these values `"b"` is no longer used and needs to be removed from each record in the table.

so `["a", "b", "c"]` should be converted to `["a", "c"]`

I have looked into using one of the postgres [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html) array_remove() but haven't been able to get it to work.

Is it possible to convert to an array type and convert back to a string after using remove?

Comment: Use the `json` or `jsonb` data type for JSON values, not `text`. There are [many functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html) for working with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `jsonb` value (cast your text if necessary) and the `-` operator:

```
UPDATE table SET col = col::jsonb - 'a';
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8dd220bf355c03a56b9f39ad465eecaa))</sup>